# AQL: return minimum of two values

Tags: arangodb

i am very new to AQL so this question is very simple i guess.

I would like to return the minimum of two values via aql. But `min(valA,valB)` returns

> [1541] invalid number of arguments for function '_AQL:MIN()'

Unfortunatly i coudn't find any functions like min, max in the documentation, so i dont know what "Invalid number of arguments" means.

Here is a minimal reproducable example:

```
for art in artikel 
return {"Preis" : min(art.preis, art.preisE,1)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AQL:MIN()  is defined for arrays not for arbitrary many parameters.
Try to use:

`for art in artikel 
return {"Preis" : min([art.preis, art.preisE,1])}`